# Is it ok to use Tagless Final (Object Algebras) on coalgebras?

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming, category-theory, tagless-final

### Background

The Haskell and Scala community have been very enamored recently with what they call tagless **final** 'pattern' of programming. These are referenced as dual to initial free algebras, so I was wondering what Tagless Final was final of. On ncatlab one only finds talk of final coalgebras, not final algebras.

Asking the Question [What Category are Tagless Final Algebras Final In](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45565/what-category-are-tagless-final-algebras-final-in/45566) on CS-Theory Stack Exchange I got a very good answer pointing to this blog post [Final Algebra Semantics is Observational Equivalence](http://prl.ccs.neu.edu/blog/2017/09/27/final-algebra-semantics-is-observational-equivalence/). So these are indeed final algebras, but not in the same category of algebras as the initial one....

### Question

Yet, when we look at how *final tagless* is **used**, we find that it is very often applied for things that look like coalgebras. See for example the two examples of a `Console` or a `UserRepository` in part 1 of [The False Hope of Managing Effects with Tagless-Final in Scala](https://dzone.com/articles/the-false-hope-of-managing-effects-with-tagless-fi).

So instead of having Algebras which in category theory are expressed with endofunctors `F` as maps of the form `F(X) ⟹ X`, it looks like many use `final tagless` with Coalgebras which are maps `X ⟹ F(X)`, and represent processes. Are these really the same thing? Or is something else going on here?

### ADTs and Final Tagless

#### On Algebras

Let's start by the explanations of final tagless given by Olivier Blanvillain's [Scala translation of examples taken from coursework on  in Haskell](https://gist.github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/48bb5c66dbb0557da50465809564ee80). One notices that this starts with an Algebraic Data Type that is indeed the archetype of an Algebraic structure: a Group.

In category a group can be built out of a the Polynomial Functor 
`F[X] = X×X + X + 1` which takes any type to the type that is either the pair of that type or that type or 1. Then selecting one specific type for X, say A an algebra is a function `F[A] ⟹ A`. The most widely known group is the set of positive and negative natural numbers and 0 denoted ℤ, and so our algebra is:

```
ℤ×ℤ + ℤ + 1 ⟹ ℤ
```

The algebra can be decomposed into 3 function `+: ℤ×ℤ ⟹ ℤ`, `-: ℤ ⟹ ℤ` and the constant `zero: 1 ⟹ ℤ`. If we vary the type X we get different algebras, and these form a category, with morphisms between them, where the most important one is the initial algebra.

The initial algebra is the free one  which allows one to build all the structure without ever loosing any information. In [Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/adts.html) we can build the initial algebra for a group like this:

```scala
enum IExp {
   case Lit(i: Int)
   case Neg(e: IExp)
   case Add(r: IExp, l: IExp)
}
```

And we can build a simple structure using it:

```
import IExp._
val fe: IExp = Add(Lit(8), Neg(Add(Lit(1), Lit(2))))
```

The `fe` structure can then be interpreted by creating functions `IExp => Int` or `IExp => String`, which are morphisms in the category of algebras,
which one reaches by deconstructing the ADT, and recursively mapping these
to an algebra with for a specific X (eg `String` or `Int`). This morphism is known as a fold. (See the 1997 book [The Algebra of Programming, by Richard Bird and Oege de Moor](https://themattchan.com/docs/algprog.pdf))

In Tagless final this is transformed into the trait

```scala
trait Exp[T] {
  def lit(i: Int): T
  def neg(t: T): T
  def add(l: T, r: T): T
}
```

As is a set of three functions all returning the same type.
Expressions are function applications

```scala
def tf0[T] given (e: Exp[T]): T =
    import e._
    add(lit(8), neg(add(lit(1), lit(2))))
```

and these can be interpreted with a given instance

```
given as Exp[Int] {
   def lit(i: Int): Int = i
   def neg(t: Int): Int = -t
   def add(l: Int, r: Int): Int = l + r
}
tf0[Int]  // 5
```

Essentially the interpretation is the implementation of the interface
`Exp` that is `given` (or in Scala 2 `implicit`) in the context.

So here we are moving from an algebraic structure expressed from an initial ADT to a final tagless version. (See the discussion on [cstheory on what that is](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45565/what-category-are-tagless-final-algebras-final-in)).

#### On Coalgebras

Now if we take the `UserRepository` example from [The False Hope of Managing Effects with Tagless-Final in Scala](https://dzone.com/articles/the-false-hope-of-managing-effects-with-tagless-fi), we have

```scala
trait UserRepository {
  def getUserById(id: UserID): User
  def getUserProfile(user: User): UserProfile
  def updateUserProfile(user: User, profile: UserProfile): Unit
}
```

this is clearly (for anyone who has read some of Bart Jacobs' work starting with [Objects and Classes Coalgebraically](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.7619&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) a coalgebra on the state S of `UserRepository`.
A Coalgebra is the dual of an Algebra: the arrows are reversed.
Starting from a Functor F, and a specific type S an coalgebra
is a function `S ⟹ F[S]`

In the case of a user repository we can see this to be

```
S ⟹ (Uid → User) × (User → Profile) × (User × Profile → S)
```

Here the functor `F(X)` takes any type `X` to a 3-tuple of functions. 
The coalgebra is such a functor F, a set of states S, and
a transition morphism `S ⟹ F(S)`.  We have 2 observational methods `getUserById` and `getUserProfile` and one state changing one `updateUserProfile` also known as a setter. By varying the type of states
we vary the coalgebra. If we look at all coalgebras on such a functor F, and the morphisms between them, we get a category of coalgebras. Of which the most important one is the final one which gives the structure of all observations on the coalgebras of that functor.

For more info on coalgebras and their relation to OO see the work by Bart Jacobs such as his [Tutorial on (co)Algebras and (co)Induction](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/40bb/e9978e2c4080740f55634ac58033bfb37d36.pdf) or [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/bblfish/status/1172265457153392640).

Essentially we have a process such as a UserRepository or a Console that have state and can change state, whereas it does not make sense to think
of change of state for a number.

Now it is true that in the Tagless Final example of UserRepository it is Genericised by a Functor `F[_]`, like this:

```scala
trait UserRepository[F[_]] {
  def getUserById(id: UserID): F[User]
  def getUserProfile(user: User): F[UserProfile]
  def updateUserProfile(user: User, profile: UserProfile): F[Unit]
}
```

Is that enough to change UserRepository into an algebra? It does in a way look like the functions all have the same range of type F[_], but does that really work? What if F is the Identity functor? Then we have the previous case.

Going the other way, from Final Tagless to an ADT, one should ask what would it be to have an ADT for `UserRepository`? 
(I have written something like that myself to model commands to change [a remote RDF database](https://github.com/read-write-web/rww-play/blob/dev/app/rww/ldp/LDPCommand.scala) and found that really helpful, but I am not sure if this is correct mathematically.)

### Further References

- The influential Haskell [Typed Tagless Final Interpreters](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf) lecture notes
- A translation of that article for Scala (Dotty) [Revisiting Tagless Final Interpreters](https://gist.github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/48bb5c66dbb0557da50465809564ee80)
- A blog post [From Object Algebras to Finally Tagless Interpreters](https://oleksandrmanzyuk.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/from-object-algebras-to-finally-tagless-interpreters-2/) makes the case that Object algebras are equivalent to Tagless Final.
- It cites the paper [Extensibility for the Masses, practical extensibility with Object Algebras](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2012/ecoop2012.pdf).

Two advantages claimed of Tagless Final are

- it makes testing easy: by moving to programming with interfaces one can 
  easily create mock implementations of the interface to test code such as database access, IO, etc...
- it is extensible: one can easily extend an 'algebra' with new methods overcoming what is known as the expression problem. (The expression problem is nicely illustrated in the blog post [From Object Algebras to Finally Tagless Interpreters](https://oleksandrmanzyuk.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/from-object-algebras-to-finally-tagless-interpreters-2/)).

The following looks like it could provide a clue:

The recent article [Codata in Action](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-17184-1_5) claims that codata (a coalgebraic concept) is the bridge between functional and OO programming, and actually uses the visitor pattern described (also used in [Extensibility for the Masses](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2012/ecoop2012.pdf)) to map between data and codata. [see illustration](https://twitter.com/bblfish/status/1173269815802441728). The claims for codata are the language agnostic representation of procedural abstraction (called modularity above), and the testability comes from the multiple implementations of an interface that Jacobs decribes with the category for a coalgebra.

Comment: My comment on the cstheory question might help. "final tagless" is really a reification of the fold over a type, without committing to being able to do anything but to apply the fold. So it's mildly observational in that sense. But folds are firmly initial.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question? You've provided a lot of interesting references, but if "*Is … OK*" (from the title - there's no question in the body of your post) is your only question that sounds very opinion-based (close-worthy).

Comment: The question is that the examples given for Tagless final in the literature I cited in the first four papers in the Further References section all use algebraic examples. Yet the usage of Final Tagless is often on coalgebraic structures (the UserRepository Example). I am wondering if the theory for Tagless Final correctly extends to those coalgebraic usages.

Comment: Quite a lot of usages of tagless is about avoiding commitment to particular IO or IO + MTL, without the overhead of Free. In such case, `F[A] => A` is about running your side effects, which is something you rarely want your generic library to do, as you want to do it yourself. It could be done via `Coalgebra`, but why would you want to define abstraction and then use it only once at the end of the world? It doesn't refute usefulness of Coalgebra for F in general, just most common use cases don't need it, or simply uses some natural transformation instead.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The `F[A] => A` that define algebras is not the same thing as the `unsafeRun:: IO => A` or `get` on a future. I'll try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two types of algebras is one between effectful and non effectful algebras. Indeed one can write the UserRepo with a GADT in Dotty (Scala3) like this too:

```
enum UserRepo[A]{
  case GetUserById(id: UserID) extends UserRepo[User]
  case GetUserProfile(user: User) extends  UserRepo[UserProfile]
  case UpdateUserProfile(user: User, profile: UserProfile) extends UserRepo[Unit]
}
```

If we leave aside the problem of [how final tagless relates to algebras](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45565/what-category-are-tagless-final-algebras-final-in/45566) and accept that they are isomorphic to GADTs, then we can rephrase the problem in terms of algebras. There it looks like Andrej Bauer has answered the problem in detail in lecture notes from March 2019 [What is Algebraic about Effects and Handlers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.05923.pdf).

Andrej Bauer clearly explains what algebras are, starting from signatures, and moving on to explain what interpretations and models of a theory are.
Then he moves on in "§2 Computational Effects as Algebraic Operations" to model effectful computations by parameterisation of algebras. When that is done we get very similar looking algebras to the ones I was wondering about.

In "§4 What is coalgebraic about algebraic effects and Handlers?" he shows how the dual of such parameterised algebras give us co-interpretations, co-models and co-operations for what are quite clearly coalgebras.

I am told these ways of handling effects are not the same as using monads, and I need to work out what the difference is, and if this affects the problem.

Comment: You might be interested in these (somewhat outdated by now) slides on [programming with comodels](https://danel.ahman.ee/talks/msr19.pdf) by Danel Ahman and myself. We're actively working on this stuff and will soon relase something.